# CSHTML, Changing a value with EditorFor, do not want old value displayed?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm sorry if this question is unclear or I'm not giving enough information, I'm new to CSHTML, and cannot tell if I'm missing something incredibly obvious.

I currently have an EditorFor() in my view that changes the password of a specific userCard field in a database. When this password is being changed, I would like the textbox to be empty, but every time it displays the old value. Deleting the value prior to edit is not an option, for my page has too many options for the user to go to a different page and leave the account passwordless. Any help?

The offending EditorFor is below:

```
<div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <h5>Enter a New Passcode</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.userCard.password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control"} })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.userCard.password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

The controller methods for this viewpage are below:

```
    public ActionResult EditPasscode(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        UserCardOBJ userCardOBJ = new UserCardOBJ();
        userCardOBJ.userCard = db.UserCards.Find(id);

        if (userCardOBJ.userCard == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(userCardOBJ);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult EditPasscode([Bind(Include = "ID,password")] UserCard userCard)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //db.Entry(userCard).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.UserCards.Attach(userCard);
            db.Entry(userCard).Property(model => model.password).IsModified = true;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(userCard);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a value property to the htmlAttribute anonymous type passed in.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.userCard.password, new { @class = "form-control", @value = "" } })
```

Comment: When I capitalized the "V" in "@value", this solution worked! Thank you so much.

Comment: Oh yeah that's right! I didn't have an environment to make sure. Glad it helped.